# How can I set the compression level (to none) with Zip File System

Tags: java, zip, compression

I am using the [Zip File System Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) to create a zip archive:

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip");
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
```

How can I set the compression level to none and what would be the default compression level.

I checked the [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemproviderprops.html) (env) there are no options targeting this.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the Java Version, there are different possibilities.

**for Java versions >= 7 and < 12**

- using the zipfs, you cannot control the compression level, as the default is used
- alternatively, you could use `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` where you can control the compression method per `ZipEntry`
  a starting point might be this post [Creating ZIP and JAR Files](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/creating-zip-and-jar-files)

**for Java versions >= 12**

- there is an option `noCompression` to control the compression method
- the important parts are

  ```
   Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
   // to store the files in the ZIP
   env.put("noCompression", "true");

   FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
  ```

**Java >= 14**

The option will be renamed from `noCompression` to `compressionMethod` (see this CSR [JDK-8231248](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8231248)).

**edit:** Based on the comment from [@Phil Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4410356/phil-brown), I did some quick research for Java 11 and the "noCompression" option.

- AdoptOpenJDK [11.0.3_7](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.3%2B7/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.3_7.tar.gz) supports it
- Azul Zulu JDK [11.0.3 (11.31.11)](https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu11.31.11-ca-jdk11.0.3-linux_x64.tar.gz) supports it
- Oracle JDK [11.0.3](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html) does not support It (also not supported till version [11.0.10](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html))

It seems the commit [196c20c0d1](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/196c20c0d14d99cc08fae64a74c802b061231a41) in the OpenJDK source was backported to some Java 11 builds, but not into all (at least it's missing in Oracle JDK 11). So if you want to use this option with a Java 11 version, you need to check if the option is supported by your specific vendor JDK/JRE.

Comment: AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.10+9 supports the "noCompression" option for ZipFileSystem.